# Do not add content filter on page template

Tags: functions

I do not want to have a function loaded by my theme on a page template.

1. Is this the correct syntax?
2. What does 99 mean here? `add_filter('the_content', 'oswc_formatter', 99);`
3. Could I apply the condition on the `add_filter` instead of what I did?

This is my code:

```
function oswc_formatter($content) {
if( !is_page_template( 'template-flat.php' ) ) {    
    $new_content = '';

    /* Matches the contents and the open and closing tags */
    $pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';

    /* Matches just the contents */
    $pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';

    /* Divide content into pieces */
    $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    /* Loop over pieces */
    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        /* Look for presence of the shortcode */
        if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {

            /* Append to content (no formatting) */
            $new_content .= $matches[1];
        } else {

            /* Format and append to content */
            $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
        }
    }

    return $new_content;
    }
}

// Before displaying for viewing, apply this function
add_filter('the_content', 'oswc_formatter', 99);
add_filter('widget_text', 'oswc_formatter', 99);
```

Comment: could someone please help me fix  the formatting of the code? I think there is a bug with stackexchange..

Answer (score 0):

ok here is the answer.. pheww

```
function oswc_formatter($content) {
if( is_page_template( 'template-flat.php' ) ) { 
return $content;
}else{
    $new_content = '';

    /* Matches the contents and the open and closing tags */
    $pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';

    /* Matches just the contents */
    $pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';

    /* Divide content into pieces */
    $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    /* Loop over pieces */
    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        /* Look for presence of the shortcode */
        if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {

            /* Append to content (no formatting) */
            $new_content .= $matches[1];
        } else {

            /* Format and append to content */
            $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
        }
    }

    return $new_content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using a plugin but if you do, It's not recommended to edit it since your changes would be overwritten the next time you update it.

The other way to deactivate the filter on condition would be:

```
if( is_page_template( 'template-flat.php' ) ){
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'oswc_formatter');
    remove_filter( 'widget_text', 'oswc_formatter');
}
```

The 99 you've got on the filter is the priority. The lower it is, the earlier it'll be executed. So you filter here will be executed as one of the latest.